# How to Store a Specific blank fields of user who is already Exist in the models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

**Views.py**

This my code as you can see in views.py file i am deriving the fields using request object
I could have used form.save() but i am getting an error.
I want to store this field data to that user model 
User is already Exist i had Used UserCreationForm

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,CreateView
from auctions.models import User
from auctions import forms
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import settings
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
#
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = forms.ProfileSetupForm
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('auctions:profile_update')
    # template_name = 'index.html'
    users =User.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['users'] = self.users
        context['form']=forms.ProfileSetupForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            address= request.POST['address']
            mobile = request.POST['mobile']
            city =request.POST['city']
            state = request.POST['state']
            birth_date =request.POST['birth_date']
            image=request.FILES['image']
            # file= request.FILES['image']
            user_name=request.POST['user_name']
            pincode = request.POST['pincode']
            print("abc",pincode,user_name,image)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')



class ThanksPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'thanks.html'
```

**forms.py**

Here in forms.py file two fields first_name and last_name comes from auth.models.User i assume

```
class ProfileSetupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # def save(self, commit=True):
    #     user= models.User()

    class Meta():
        fields=('image','first_name','last_name','address','mobile','birth_date','city','state','pincode')
        model=models.User
        # widgets={
        #
        # }
```

**models.py**

Here auth.models.User are inherited so few fields will be there which are not written like first_name,username etc

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='To be Setup')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13,default='To be Setup')
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    pincode = models.IntegerField(default='000000')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='Place to be Selected.')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='To be Selected')
    #proof_document= models.FileField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    profile_setup = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '@{}'.format(self.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})  # This represent after doing Comment Where user should redirect

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.HomePage.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auctions/',include('auctions.urls',namespace='auctions')),
    path('thanks/', views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name='thanks'),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

**Template: index.html**

Here it will check weather user is authenticated if he is the it will check if user profile has been set on not if not then fill the form and data will be go to views.py  class HomePage metho post

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load bootstrap4%}

{%block title%}
Welcome To AuctionHouse
{%endblock%}


{%block content%}
    {%if user.is_authenticated%}
        {%for current_user in users%}
            {%ifequal user.username current_user.username%}
                {%ifequal current_user.profile_setup False %}
                <div class="container">
<!--&lt;!&ndash;                    -->
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {%csrf_token%}
                    {%bootstrap_form form%}
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="{{user.username}}">
                    <input type="submit" value="Set this a Profile"></form>
                 </div>
                {%endifequal%}
                {%ifequal current_user.profile_setup True %}


               Something

                {% endifequal %}
            {% endifequal %}
        {%endfor%}
    {%else%}
        <p>Not authenticated....</p>
    {%endif%}
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: " I could have used form.save() but i am getting an error. I want to store this field data to that user model User is already Exist i had Used UserCreationForm" => you have to create a specific ModelForm for your custom User model (looks like you already did FWIW) __AND pass the user instance to be updated to the form__ (else it tries to create a new one indeed). This is all documented FWIW.

Comment: Do you know what did i do worng?